# How do I update a JSON and then output it again?

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a JSON this is loaded and output directly the user can now enter something and as soon as he presses a button the JSON should be updated (this also works, in the console.log() it is output correctly) My question is now how can I output the JSON again with the update set?

```
    import React from 'react'
    import CardItem from '../pages/CardItem'
    import PostData from '../../data/post.json'
    import './Box.css';

    const [value_Text, setValue_Text] = useState('')
    const [jsonDataDisplayed, setJsonDataDisplayed] = useState(JsonMessages)
    const sendMessage = () => {
    
            var newJson = {
            "id": jsonDataDisplayed.length+1,
            "title": value_Text
        }
       
          //console.log(jsonDataDisplayed);
          setJsonDataDisplayed({newJson})
          console.log(jsonDataDisplayed);
          // ToDo update the JSON below
          // ...
          //  First Click only the 'normal' JSON is shown with the three elements
          // Second Click only the added element is shown 
    }
    
    
    function Cards() {
        return (
          <div className='cards'>
            <div className='cards__container'>
                <div className='cards__wrapper'>
                    <ul className='cards__items'>
                    {PostData.map((postDetail, index)=>{
                        return <div>
                            <Card
                            src={postDetail.src}
                            text={postDetail.title}
                            />
                        </div>
                    })} 
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
              <input type="email"  onChange={event => setValue_Text(event.target.value)} />
              <Button type="button" onChange={sendMessage}/>
          </div>
        );
      }
    
    export default Cards
```

JSON

```
[ 
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Text 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Text 2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Text 3"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to store the json in a state.
the component rerenders only when a state that is related to it's jsx is changed.

*note: when you use the set function of the state you should give a new object and not the updated json because react wouldn't recognize it as change*

```
const [postDataDisplayed, setPostDataDisplayed] = useState(PostData)
const sendMessage = () => {

      PostData.push(value_Text);
      console.log(JsonMessages);
      setPostDataDisplayed({...PostData}) // es6 way to clone object
}
```

**don't forget to update the jsx to display postDataDisplayed instead of PostData**

Comment: And how do I update the function right? With `jsonDataDisplayed.map((oneMessage...` I got the error `TypeError: jsonDataDisplayed.map is not a function`

Comment: How do I add my new JSON to the old JSON?
If I add text I press the button, then the old JSON is shown to me if I press the button again only the newest JSON object is shown to me

Comment: `var newJson = {
                "id": postDataDisplayed.length+1,
                "title": value_Text,
            }
            setJsonDataDisplayed({...newJson})`

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is, using another state.

---

```
const [value_Text, setValue_Text] = useState('')
const [dataToDisplay, setDataToDisplay] = useState(PostData);

const sendMessage = () => {

      // Please keep in mind that you getting objects out of PostData.
      // This means that you need to also pass a object.
     
       const newData = {
         id: dataToDisplay.length + 1,
         title: value_Text
       };
      
      // Update the state to your new Data set by mergin new and old together. 
      setDataToDisplay([...dataToDisplay, newData]);
    
  
}


...
```

**Working Example**

[image: Edit confident-glade-1xc9z]